# Multiple sites (separate domains) running from one WordPress site

Tags: multisite

I have a new project which is a little different.

I have a main Group website and then multiple sister sites which are under the same company umbrella.

They want one WordPress website to control Team Members / News / Projects. I've done a little research and found out about WordPress multi site. Would this be applicable for what I'm after? Each sister site has it's own domain / theme and different content but they only want to have to update one site which would simultaneously update them all. I was thinking I'd have all the pages static apart from Team / News / Projects. Would everything all be on one server or are they on separate servers linked to one database?

Am I right in thinking that WP Multisite is what I should be exploring? Sorry if this seems like an obvious question, it's all new to me this time!

Comment: I would say Multisite is probably the best option my friend. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Multisite is the way to go. Each sub-site can have it's own domain name, as in www.example.com/site1 or site1.example.com or even www.yourdomain.com .

Lots of help on the googles and the WP codex area on how to set up and configure multisite for your needs.